# Partial Deployment of an App in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have updated a new release my existing app in Google Play Console with partial deployment of 10%.
What does this mean to new users, which do not own the app already ?
Do new users get the new release by chance of 10% or do all new users get the new release ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 10% includes existing users and new users. So 1 out of 10 new users will get the new version (same for existing users).

Comment: How to install latest release on own android phone? Because it is difficult to be on 10% user...

Comment: Publish the APK/Bundle on a closed track and add yourself to the list of users eligible to that track.